# How to display top and side menu in SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony, menu, sonata-admin

There are no documents talk about that. Please help me. Thank you

[image: SonataAdminBundle with top menu and side menu]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Admin top menu** is created automatically based on `group` item in admin service definition. All admin services can be grouped and are displayed in top menu.

[Example](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/admin.xml#L30) (see `group="sonata_page"` where `sonata_page` is name of menu group):

**Admin side menu** can be created with `configureSideMenu()` method in your admin service.
[Example](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/master/Admin/PageAdmin.php#L267)

Comment: Any way to change the position of the Admin side menu from left to right?

Comment: As far as I know there is no option for menu position. You can try to define some custom css rules.