# Sonata how to add to the menu

Tags: symfony, menu, sonata-admin

I want to build the menu in the left of Sonata like the picture below.
I have a controller in front end Symfony, how can I add the link to this menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your layout should extend: "SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig" and overwrite the "side_bar_nav" block from sonata. That's it.

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}  

{% block side_bar_nav %}  
    {% include 'MyBundleBundle:Default:menu.html.twig' %}  
{% endblock %}
```

Change sonata template in app/admin/config.yml:

```
 sonata_admin:
    title: "Admin"
    templates:
        layout: MyBundleBundle:CRUD:standard_layout.html.twig
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you please add the name of the file which contains this code?

Comment: Should be your layout: src/MyApplication/MybundleBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/standard_layout.html.twig

Comment: I suggest you to add the name of the file in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `configureSideMenu()` function in your adminController

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837194/how-to-display-top-and-side-menu-in-sonataadminbundle)

Answer (score 0):

I add my menu items via `YourBundle\Bundle\Resources\config\services.yml`

```
services:
    acme_recept.admin.recept:
        class: Acme\Bundle\YourBundle\Admin\ReceptAdmin
        arguments: [~, Acme\Bundle\YourBundle\Entity\Recept, SkreprReceptBundle:ReceptAdmin]
        tags:
            - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, **group: Administrator**, **label: Recepten**}
```

Via tags you can give the label for the menu-item